Renewing your application certificate in Microsoft Entra ID
We are using Content Hub.
One of our vendors has received the following email from Microsoft to renew the certificate.
The vendor team who has the access to Microsoft Entra ID says that can renew the certificate.
There is a second part to this which says Download the new certificate and upload it to MyCompany - Sitecore Content Hub - Production.
We have no idea what the second part means. Can this cert be uploaded from the Content Hub portal or should it be done from elsewhere.
When we contacted Sitecore they said, it is out of their scope of technical support and suggested Sitecore360.
Could anyone please let me know where and how to upload this new cert.
Thank you
Email content:

Please renew your application certificate in MyCompany Ltd.
You’re receiving this notification because your email address is associated
with MyCompany - Sitecore Content Hub - Production. The certificate used for
single sign-on to MyCompany - Sitecore Content Hub - Production is going to
expire in 29 days.
Recommended action
We recommend you renew the certificate in MyCompany -
Sitecore Content Hub - Production before October 30, 2024 23:11 UTC to
avoid downtime with single sign-on.
Please follow the steps below.
.....(Removed the steps to renew).
Download the new certificate and
upload it to MyCompany - Sitecore Content Hub - Production. Rolling the
certificate in Microsoft Entra ID and configuring it in your app may
cause single sign-on downtime. Please plan for potential downtime when
performing the steps above.


Did you check the user sign in scripts, is there any reference to certificate there on the code.

You can upload the certificate to the Portal Assets section by clicking on Manage -> Portal Assets and create a public link for your certificate there.
I found this reference in the Content Hub doc page https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/authentication-configuration-example.html where it references the certificate in the saml authentication (Path: Manage -> Settings -> Portal Configuration -> Authentication).

You can check the current value of the "certificate" parameter of your existing SAML configuration and see where the value points to, try to replace that with the public link of the new certificate that you uploaded to your Portal Assets.

I could not find the certificate property in the existing JSON here. Is this expected.

@sukesh yes, that is expected. You don't need to provide certificate inside JSON. Purely depends on how the identity provider is configured. You need to reach out to your IT team to find out more details.

You can check for the certificate setting by navigating to the Settings-> Portal Configuration -> Authentication in the Sitecore Content Hub, inside the Saml external authentication provider as below.

Inside the above configuration, you can configure certificate path of the new certificate that is used for signing message.
Note: When adding the certificate you will also need to provide the password for the certificate in case any. The certificate is only required if AuthnRequestsSigned is true in the the service provider metadata file.
More details on the same can found here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

I could not find the certificate property in the existing JSON here. Is this expected.

@sukesh Can you check with the vendor team who is managing the entra id that AuthnRequestsSigned=true in the service provider metadata file. If it is false, then you dont need to do any changes..
